# How to get the TEXT from a layers attributes to display on my map

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes

I'm totally new with GIS software, so I apologize if this is a question that's already been answered!

I'm working with the Texas Landgrid. It's composed of Leagues, Labors, Blocks, Townships, Sections, Surveys and Abstracts (Super confusing at times!). I've managed to find the shapefiles for the landgrid, but I haven't found a way to get the text to appear on the map. I'll provide screenshots for examples as to what I'm talking about.

Here is a screenshot from drilling info.com:
[image: DrillingInfo Landgrid Example]

And here is a screenshot from my QGIS project:
[image: QGIS Landgrid Example]

As you can see, none of the text is displayed in my QGIS map, so it's improbable for me to be able to locate specific tracts of land for my purposes.

I have found that the data for Surveys, abstracts, blocks, etc. is contained within the "TX Land Grid" layer as attributes. (COUNTYID, SURVEYABS1, SURVEYNAME, SURVEYBLO3 & SURVEYSEC4).

So my question is, can I somehow get these attributes to display as text in a similar way to the screenshot from DrillingInfo? I need to be able to see the names/numbers within the separate tracts of land.

Here is a link to a zip file containing the "TX Land Grid" shapefile.
[TX Land Grid Shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CQADPHAVBme4PAh1agMjqrA8tiwGY72E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, that's called *labeling*. Open the style manager and choose a field to display as a label, or concatenate several fields to see several attributes. For more details, read the appropriate section of the QGIS user manual: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#labels-properties

Comment: Thank you! Like I said, I'm totally new to GIS software, and wasn't sure where or how to search for what I needed. Thanks, for answering my question.

Comment: Happy to help. Often it's just about knowing the right search term.

Comment: I'd say in a roundabout way it is a duplicate of that question. Like you said, I just didn't know the right terms, so that question didn't appear in my searches.